# Find number of occurence of each element Xpath 1.0

Tags: xml, xpath

So I have this xml that looks like this :

```
<session number="1" name="NameOfMySession">
    <article number="16">
        <title>The title of my article 1</title>
        <author name="Tetsuya Sakai"    lab="OneLab" country="Japan"/>
        <author name="Tatsuya Uehara"   lab="OneLab" country="Japan"/>
        <author name="Taishi Shimomori" lab="OneLab" country="Japan"/>
        <author name="Makoto Koyama"    lab="OneLab" country="Japan"/>
    </article>
    <article number="19">
        <title>The title of my article 2</title>
        <author name="Aiden R. Doherty"     lab="TheLab" country="Ireland"/>
        <author name="Alan F. Smeaton"      lab="TheLab" country="Ireland"/>
        <author name="Keansub Lee"          lab="TheLab" country="USA"/>
        <author name="Makoto Koyama"        lab="OneLab" country="Japan"/>
    </article>
</session>
```

I am trying to find how can I get the name of authors that have written multiple article.

My idea was to count the number of time an author appears in the .xml and if that count was greater than 1 just display the name. But for some reason I just can't figure out how to do that.

So if you have any ideas on how to do that it would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the author names where there's a following article with an author of the same name, and not a preceding one (to return repeated authors only once.)

```
/session/article/author/@name[
    . = following::article/author/@name and
    not(. = preceding::article/author/@name)
]
```

Comment: Thank you it works well ! The only problem is if their is more than 2 occurence of the name, the name will be displayed twice. Not a big issue but I'll try to see if I can fix that.